# Search results incomplete

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

The "newest" tab on the results of an "intags:mine" search are incomplete.  (Addendum: it appears that all search results are incomplete.)  Specifically, no results newer than early 2 June are appearing.

The ordering seems fine; advancing a few pages gives me results from 31 May.  It's just that the newest results - the ones I actually want! - are missing.

The "active" tab seems to have the same issue.  For obvious reasons, it isn't easy to test the other two tabs.

This was working yesterday.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The servers were down for part of today, apparently a move in data centers. Even though the site is back, it looks like searches have not quite caught up yet. For me, I get the latest posts if I click on a tag marker, but searches for keywords do not show results beyond June 1.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: yep, looks like all searches are currently restricted to results from before early on 2 June.  Presumably this is because of the data center move and will resolve itself in due course, but I'll leave this question up for now just in case it wasn't expected.

Comment: Yes, it's still not working.

Comment: There is [network wide issue with the elasticsearch cluster](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233740/search-results-are-old-out-of-date) and there is some upgrading to Sql 2014 in the new DC taking place https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/475707602286809088

Comment: All working now, at least for me. :-)