# Searches with the new [swift-language] tag aren't working

Tags: bug, tags, search

Any attempts on stack overflow to perform a search with the new [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) tag gives 0 results.

Is this a bug? A fact of the tag being less than a week old? User error?

Example:

[[swift-language] uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift-language%5D+uitableview)

Comment: There is network wide issue with the elasticsearch cluster we think: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233740/search-results-are-old-out-of-date

Comment: Thanks. That's seem to be the problem since searches haven't been updated since the day the `[swift-language]` tag was created. I guess patience is in order at this point.

Comment: I hope we don't have to wait 6-8 weeks to get this fixed...Tomorrow [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) will give better search results than the live site...

Comment: Also reported yesterday here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258794/search-results-incomplete.

Comment: It did try some searching but, well, recent questions don't appear. :)

Comment: It's working again. Yeah.